# What does it mean "This filter supports the following commands"?

Tags: ffmpeg

In the [FFmpeg Filters Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) some filters have a subsection "Commands" which begins with the sentence

> This filter supports the following commands:

e. g. in the section [6.68 volume](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume).

Filters have *parameters*; it is understandable. But what is the meaning of filter *commands* and how and when are they used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands allow you to change the parameters *during* execution of the command. This is primarily useful when working with streaming media e.g. if the volume gets too loud during a broadcast, send a command to the volume filter to lower it.

To issue commands to filters which support it from outside, ffmpeg has to be compiled with libzmq support. See the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zmq_002c-azmq) for the zmq filter for details.

To issue commands from the terminal, press <kbd>c</kbd>

The 'command prompt' will be shown :

```
Enter command: <target>|all <time>|-1 <command>[ <argument>]
```

Enter a command as per the given format and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

e.g. `overlay@logo -1 x 100`

Comment: Thank you very much, I intensively searched for it without a success.